# Super Uninstallers that can be run from a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, uninstall, portable-apps

Does anyone know of a 'Super Uninstaller' package that will allow you to run it from a USB Flash Drive?  I used to have a CD that was a Super Uninstaller utility that would uninstall *anything*.  I can't seem to find it and I'd like to replace it with one that I can run from a flash drive.  I'd like the portability to now have to install it on each computer I'm using it on.

Any and all suggestions would be helpful!

Thanks!
JFV

Comment: Any "super uninstallers" I've seen have to be installed before you install applications, and have to regularly monitor changes to the hard drive and registry to know how to uninstall anything.  While this would be good in thought, I don't see how it's feasible in practice. The program would have to rely on the same add/remove registry that Windows does, wouldn't it?

Comment: uninstallers are some of the few programs where portability is nonsense. you want them permanently installed prior to any software installation in order to monitor and record each installation process correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the best tool i use, all the people in my IT have these on their usb sticks

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revouninstaller.zip)

> With its advanced and fast algorithm, Revo Uninstaller analyzes an application's data before uninstall and scans after you uninstall an application. After the program's regular uninstaller runs, you can remove additional unnecessary files, folders and registry keys that are usually left over on your computer. Even if you have a broken installation, Revo Uninstaller scans for an application's data on your hard disk drives and in the Windows registry and shows all found files, folders and registry keys so you can delete them.

Comment: +1: Well you answered my question above, and although it's probably a little less comprehensive than the method I expected programs would have to do, Revo's method is still pretty good.

Comment: +1: Beat me to the program I was going to recommend.  It's the best non-monitoring program I've found for uninstalling.

Comment: @Systech: It does what I need it to do!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it fits your definition of 'Super Uninstaller', but I know [CCleaner has a portable version](http://www.ccleaner.com/download/builds).

Comment: I didn't know that CCleaner had a portable version.  Not what I was looking for, but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SmartBuster](http://www.rovatronic.net/SmartBuster.htm) (it's portable, but it's a basic uninstaller )

Answer (score 0):

I like Revo Uninstaller and am using it happily.  It is freeware/donationware.  Your Uninstaller2008 works well also as a retail product.